# how to call class from different package

Tags: java, class, oop

Good Morning all, i have problem when i want call my class in different package. i have use

```
private void getExecutionReport(quickfix.Message message, String tipeMessage) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             try {
                 System.out.print("Message "+ message);
                StringField msgType = message.getHeader().getField(new MsgType());
                System.out.print("getExecutionReport "+tipeMessage);
                String symbol = message.getString(Symbol.FIELD);
                System.out.print("getExecutionReport "+symbol);
                String clorid = message.getString(ClOrdID.FIELD);
                String orderid = message.getString(OrderID.FIELD);
                String execid = message.getString(ExecID.FIELD);
                String execTransType = message.getString(ExecTransType.FIELD);
                String ordertype = message.getString(OrdType.FIELD);
                String exectype = message.getString(ExecType.FIELD);
                String orderstatus = message.getString(OrdStatus.FIELD);
                int side = message.getInt(Side.FIELD);
                Double orderqty = message.getDouble(OrderQty.FIELD);
                int leavesqty = message.getInt(LeavesQty.FIELD);
                 double price = message.getDouble(Price.FIELD);
                int cumqty = message.getInt(CumQty.FIELD);
                int lastqty = message.getInt(LastQty.FIELD);
                 //call Class in different package
```

DAOInsert.newOrderSingleInsert(tipeMessage,symbol,clorid,orderid,execid,execTransType,ordertype,exectype,orderstatus,side,orderqty,leavesqty,price,cumqty,lastqty);

```
            } catch (FieldNotFound e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
```

but when i want hit this class

```
public class DAOInsert {
    private DAOInsert dAOInsert;
    static Session sessionObj;
    static SessionFactory sessionFactoryObj;

    public final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(DAOInsert.class);

    // This Method Is Used To Create The Hibernate's SessionFactory Object
    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        // Creating Configuration Instance & Passing Hibernate Configuration File
        Configuration configObj = new Configuration();
        configObj.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");

        // Since Hibernate Version 4.x, ServiceRegistry Is Being Used
        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistryObj = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configObj.getProperties()).build(); 

        // Creating Hibernate SessionFactory Instance
        sessionFactoryObj = configObj.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistryObj);
        return sessionFactoryObj;
    }

    public static void newOrderSingleInsert(String tipeMessage, String symbol, String clorid, String orderid, String execid, String execTransType, String ordertype, String exectype, String orderstatus, int side, Double orderqty, int leavesqty, double price, int cumqty, int lastqty){
          int count = 0;
          NewOrderSingle newordersingleObj = null;
          try {
              System.out.print("DAOInsert "+tipeMessage);
              // Getting Session Object From SessionFactory
              sessionObj = buildSessionFactory().openSession();
              // Getting Transaction Object From Session Object
              sessionObj.beginTransaction();

              // Creating Transaction Entities
            //  newordersingleObj = new NewOrderSingle();             
              //newordersingleObj.setFixProtocol("FIX.4.2");
              //newordersingleObj.setBodyLength(250);
                  //sessionObj.save(newordersingleObj);

              // Committing The Transactions To The Database
              //sessionObj.getTransaction().commit();
              //logger.info("\nSuccessfully Created '" + count + "' Records In The Database!\n");
          } catch(Exception sqlException) {
              if(null != sessionObj.getTransaction()) {
                  logger.info("\n.......Transaction Is Being Rolled Back.......\n");
                  sessionObj.getTransaction().rollback();
              }
              sqlException.printStackTrace();
          } finally {
              if(sessionObj != null) {
                  sessionObj.close();
              }
          }
      }



}
```

i cannot hit this class using my first method. which is the problem when i hit my class ? please help me for fix my problem

Comment: You need to import the package that the class you want to reference is in

Comment: yes i have import it..  import com.dxtr.hibernate.DAOInsert; @NotZack

Comment: the problem is close right now